# is MySQL spatial ready for production?

Tags: spatial-database, mysql-spatial

currently I'm using PostgreSQL/PostGIS for a small spatial project. Last week the project manager asked me if we could migrate to MySQL with Spatial Extension.

I know MySQL but have no experience with the Spatial Extension. I heard that the extension is not very fast and might contain some bugs.

Now my question - is MySQL Spatial extension stable and fast enough to be considered for an online database with about 20000 spatial operations a day?

The operations are just the standard stuff like:
- export to KML
- point in polygon
- overlapping polygon

The database has one GB of spatial data.

Comment: No the MySQL Spatial Extension is still in development. You will find your current POSTGIS version more stable and more spatial functions than the MYSQL Spatial. see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/ You can still test it on a test environment

Comment: @Mapperz: Care to (expand and) post that as an answer, please?

Comment: Is "SOPD spatial operations per day" enough info? What about "CUPM concurrent users per minute" and "SOPM spatial operations per minute"? I'm not sure how _I_ would use the different info -- i'm just wondering if there are more rigorous/standard benchmarks for assessing performance.

Comment: It might help if we knew why the PM wanted to move away from PostGIS to another solution (in this case MySQL). I have trouble believing any experienced project manager would want to change infrastructure without a sound reason. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @martin f, I don't know which indicators are best for this question, I just wanted to provide a rough picture about the type and load of the implemented application. The SOPM should be around 100 and the 'CUPM'at about 30 in peak hours - so nothing serious.

Comment: @BradHards, the motivation of the PM is that PostgreSQL will not be supported anymore by the admins of the companies computer center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mapperz, the link helped to get a feeling about the status of the spatial plugin.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/